# Can I resize a software RAID-5 in Windows Server 2k8 R2 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid, raid5

I want to add a fourth disk to my software storage RAID in server 2k8 R2. I'm not seeing any way to do this with the built in disk manager, Paragon Partition Manager, or EASEUS Partition Manager.

Is this doable? I really don't have the available free disk space to back up all the data on the RAID just so I can add another disk to it.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to restore onto a fresh RAID5 rebuild.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to extend a Windows-based software RAID5, even with something like GParted? Should I use something other than RAID5? I can't really afford a RAID controller card (this is a home server), and IIRC the onboard wannabe RAID controllers that come on modern motherboards are pretty crappy.

Comment: You can only extend JBOD in software on Windows. +1 But regardless, you need to add a backup solution, unless what you're storing is completely volatile in nature and nothing you want to keep. RAID isn't backup, it's (in this case) just for improving availability and reliability.

Comment: I would still consider RAID5 backup - if a drive fails in the array, I won't lose my data immediately...

Comment: Not to sound rude, but RAID, of any level is not backup, its redundancy. It's true that you won't lose it immediately, but you are relying on software RAID, and that it will notify you properly if there is any sort of failure.